# slicknav menu doesn't appear on mobile with phonegap

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, slicknav

I am working on a mobile menu using sliknav to use in my phonegap app
the button works perfect in the browser but after building with phonegap the button just dissapears.

here's the relevant HTML code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Slicknav.css">
    <script src = "js/jquery.slicknav.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="overview.html">Overview</a></li>
    <li><a href="profilepage.html">Profile Page </a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

and the javascript function that calls the menu

```
$(function(){
label: '';
        $('#menu').slicknav();
    });
```

Comment: [JSfiddling](http://jsfiddle.net) it will help us see your problem easier

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Hvn5g/1/ here's the fiddle of the menu

Comment: confused about this `label: '';` Shouldn't it be `label= '';`

Answer (score -1):

you can use below
jQuery(function($) {$("#s4-leftpanel").slicknav();});

or
$("#s4-leftpanel").slicknav({label: 'ABC'});